# Android. Правильное обновление SQLite базы на стороне клиента

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Делаю ученическое приложение "Словарь" с функционалом, позволяющим пользователю добавить часть слов в избранное. Все слова находятся SQLite в таблице `Words`: `id|category|title|description`.

category - первая буква слова. title - само слово, description - его описание.

Думаю над тем как реализовать дистанционное добавление новых слов(обновление), чтобы у пользователя не дропнулся при этом список избранных слов, но не знаю как это сделать правильно(чтобы не всплыли косяки в будущем). Сейчас делаю так:

Создал отдельный класс, который создаёт отдельную  базу с таблицой "UserFavorites" с избранными записями, которые заносятся в эту таблицу по клику. Обновлённые версии баз планирую выкладывать на хостинг и обновлять либо тупо дропом, заменяя текущую версию новой, либо реализовать добавление новых записей в `onUpdate()`. Выглядит работоспособно, но с двумя базами много мороки и путаницы.

Был ещё вариант добавить в `Words` поле `isFavorite` и забить на вторую базу. Но это видится мне не стабильным, падает основная база и всё теряется.

Вопрос: как сделать правильно? Куда копнуть нужно?

Comment: Т.е. не сам пользователь заносит новые слова, а сервер их выдает? Для избранного, нужно не отдельную базу делать, а использовать `ALTER TABLE` чтобы добавить в таблицу колонку для избранного. При обновлении базы не нужно ее дропать, нужно проверять, если такая запись уже есть - то пропускать ее в обновлении. естественно чтобы самому не запутаться - id слова на сервере и id слова в приложении должны совпадать. А чтобы не терялись данные пользователя - можно использовать либо API и хранить инфу на сервере, или firebase например.

Comment: дополню ответ выше. Посмотрите в сторону Room. 
Он вам решит проблема с обновлением.  Вы можете добавить дополнительное поле(isFavourite) для вашей таблицы и задать ему значение по умолчанию. А при обновление данных, игнорировать это поле.  Новые записи он будет добавлять с isFavoirite. А так же можно реализовать и удаление. И у вас будет аналогичная бд в телефоне и на сервере.
Вы можете повесить слушателя на обновление данных, и у вас всегда будут актуальные данные.